# Best way for "LINQ where in <list>" when <list> has many elements?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I know I can filter my orders like below to get all orders with the given numbers:

```
var numbers = new[] { 23, 44, 54 };
var filteredOrders = from order in orders.Order
                     where numbers.Contains(order.Number)
                     select order;
```

- But how does this query behave if my list of numbers becomes big, like 10000 elements?
- Is there a better way to do it for big number lists?

Comment: If you're using EF then that might actually throw errors. The best solution depends on your situation, but one option is to insert those numbers into the database and do a `JOIN`.

Comment: How many `orders.Order` are possible compared to the size of `numbers`?

Comment: @NetMage: Maybe 10k orders and 5k numbers?